# Does an application have access to the cached data in another application?

Tags: ipad

The reason I am raising this question is security concerns. Applications like Twitter might access a user's browsing behaviour by checking the cached history on user's Safari browser for example if inter-application access is somehow permitted through coding. Since I don't program in Objective-C and do not have the time to delve into its documentation, would someone be able to shed some light on this in general terms? This question is geared towards the new iPad, but I think the answer, if any, probably applies to all iOS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each app is placed in it's own sandbox which limits the app's access to files etc.

More info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

Comment: Good stuff and good to know!!